# Do not add TITLE as heading to body when exporting org file

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

This export option:

```
#+TITLE: My title
```

Does two things:

1. adds a meta tag on the document's `head`: `<title>My title</title>`
2. adds a heading at the start of the generated `content` `div`: `<h1 class="title">My title</h1>`

I want 1 but do not want 2. Is it possible to configure this?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this "should" work according to http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings:

```
#+OPTIONS: title:nil
#+HTML_HEAD: <title>My special title</title>
```

but in my setup this doesn't actually suppress the title. it does add an extra `<title>` to the head block though with the text you put in.

If you make the title blank, e.g.

```
#+TITLE:
```

then there is no title, but still apparently two titles in the head. Is that close to what you want?

Comment: Not sure when or how this was fixed, but your answer seems to work fine in current master. I have not tested maint. EDIT: You don't have to make the title blank.

Comment: it dosen't work - org-version 9.4.6. It creates two <title> tags in head - first one is blank - and browser (firefox 90.0.2) dosen't bother with second one. It reads only the first one.

Answer (score 2):

[Org mode version 9.5.2]

Part of John Kitchin's answer helped me; the following achieves what you need:

```
#+TITLE: grtcdr's website
#+OPTIONS: title:nil
```

Comment: Works also with v9,4,4! Upvoted. Should be accepted answer.